# Android SoundPool Class acts weird in my application

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, performance

I have a song playing continuously in background using an Android `MediaPlayer`, by continuously I mean it loops forever.

I also have `25-30`  short sounds that I play at discrete duration's using `SoundPool` Class, and they also have to play again and again with the main song.

The sounds are `0.5` second duration each and some of them are `0.7Mb` in size, while the average size of a song would be approximately `0.4Mb`.

I am able to do this entire thing smoothly on the device I made this app on, then I came to know that SoundPool has problems playing on Dual Core Phones. So I withdrew support for them.

Lately I tested the app on an older device running 2.3.3 and the new problem is that the sounds seem to play properly for first 4-5 cycles, i.e. till the main song plays 4-5 times, then at 6th time, there is a noticeable delay in the playing of sounds, I logged the values of `SoundPool.play()` and found out that delay is ~(1-2 sec), and this issue is only on lower end phones, why is this happening, I suppose that the problem is caused by the `SoundPool` class and is not at all an hardware issue since the device I tested it on had ample `RAM` i.e. `500Mb` and a decent `600Mhz` processor.

I really need to fix this as I expect my app to run on most devices, except dual core phone for time being.

Also I cannot use MediaPlayer to play my sounds as I do not want to increase CPU overhead and make my app lag more and also I do not know how many sounds I want to play before hand.

Any clue on how to fix this issue and reduce the lag, is most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Audio / Video playback is usually problematic since there are a lot of hardware / lowlevel software factors involved (there might be specialized decoding hardware on separate chips and/or embedded into the cpu and all of that in combination with software decoders, switching between bluetooth, headphonejack and the 2 speakers you have, a huge software stack from kernel to android system, etc). It is probably the most fragile subsystem of Android devices. A lot of devices have smaller quirks in that area and it isn't directly Mhz / RAM / Dualcore related. And unfortunately you have to live with some of them :(

Your best bet is to experiment with different ways to play / compress your audio. Things like restarting the playback after 5 cycles etc